# could not create a list of fields for the query ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I got this query that I am trying to use for dataset for SSRS report, but I keep getting the error

> Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can
> connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.

My datasource connection is fine and I suspect that maybe because I join on fields with same names I get this error but can someone please help where exactly is the problem. My sql query is

```
SELECT oaem.CreatedOn, oaem.IsActive, oac.FirstName, oac.LastName, oac.Nationality,
       oaa.Country as Residence,oaem.ExternalReference, oaem.OnboardingApplicantId
FROM [audit].[OnboardingApplicantExternalUserMapping] as oaem 
left join [dbo].[OnboardingApplicantClients] as oac
    on oac.OnboardingApplicantId = oaem.OnboardingApplicantId
left join [dbo].[OnboardingApplicantAddresses] as oaa
    on oac.OnboardingApplicantId = oaa.OnboardingApplicantId
left join [dbo].[OnboardingApplicants] as oa
    on oac.OnboardingApplicantId = oa.Id
WHERE oaem.IsActive = 0
ORDER BY AuditDate desc
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you select from just one table?

Comment: unfortunately no, The data I need is in all those tables

Comment: So you get the same error if you select from one table only?

Comment: I get the error when I use [audit].[OnboardingApplicantExternalUserMapping], if I use the same table but different scema, like [dbo].[OnboardingApplicantExternalUserMapping] its ok, but I must use the one with audit cos I got the AuditDate only there

Comment: It is strange that you order by AuditDate but do not include it in your SELECT list. How do you know the ordering is correct and useful. Regardless, best practice is to always define an alias for every table and use it when referencing every column. In this case, try adding the appropriate alias to your use of AuditDate.